# Javascript href not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, href

I have the following code snippet that works on all browsers except for Safari:

```
<a href="javascript:void (0);" onclick="javascript:myfunction (x,y);"><span>something here </span></a>
```

How can I make this work in Safari?
Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: You shouldn't write `javascript:` in any `on___` attribute

Comment: This should work. Use either href or onclick. Using both might be confusing browser which to run. Try running only `href="javascript:myfunction (x,y);"`

Comment: this works fine on safari 9.1.2

Comment: 2 versions of safari. My buddy has a macbook pro up to date. I tested it on the only vs I could find for windows 5.1.7

Comment: Rehban your code actually works great. Thanks for the tip. Gonna have to make sure it doesn't break the other browsers functionality... I'm guessing it shouldn't

Comment: It won't, unless something is wrong. It is the right way of doing btw

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Should I add it as a answer then?

Comment: By all means. It helped me fix my issue so I'd be more than happy to accept it

Comment: Cool, I'll add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Use either href or onclick. Using both might be confusing browser which to run. Try running only `href="javascript:myfunction (x,y);"`

Comment: Thanks, Happy Coding